# How should I use the MS Graph API for Search on a specific SharePoint Site?

Tags: c#, .net-core, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

How do I use the Microsoft Graph API to search on a very specific site, such as: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipment ? If I explore the Graph API it only seems to be able to search on the root or all sites.

Answer (score 0):

You could use filters in search queries to search on a specific SharePoint site, for example:

```
"queryString":"path:\"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipment\""
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-5-use-filters-in-search-queries